# Segfault from atoi

Tags: c, multithreading, pointers

I'm new to writing threaded code and rusty with C. I've tried debugging with gdb, and it looks like I'm getting a segfault after I try to set the value of num using atoi, but I'm not sure why. Can anyone explain this segfault?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int *ptr;

int getFibonacciNumber(int num)
{
    if ( num <= 1 ) return num;
    else if ( ptr[num] != 0 ) return ptr[num];
    else{
        int fibOfNMO = getFibonacciNumber(num - 1);
        int fibOfNMT = getFibonacciNumber(num - 2);
        ptr[num] = fibOfNMO + fibOfNMT;
        return ptr[num];
    }
}

void* fibonacci(void* arg)
{
    int* num = (int*)arg;
    int fib = getFibonacciNumber(*(num));

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("%s", argv[0]);
    pthread_t tid_main;
    pthread_t tid_fib;
    int ret;
    int* num;
    *num = atoi(argv[0]);

    if ( argv[0] != NULL ) ptr = (int*)malloc((*(num) + 1)*sizeof(int));
    else exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < *(num) + 1; ++i) ptr[i] = 0;
    ptr[1] = 1;

    printf("%d\n", getFibonacciNumber(6));
    ret = pthread_create(&tid_fib, NULL, fibonacci, num);
    if (ret) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error -- pthread_create() failed.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

    ret = pthread_join(tid_fib, NULL);
    if (ret) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error -- pthread_join() failed.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

    printf("%d\n", ptr[*(num)]);
    free(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int* num;
*num = atoi(argv[0]);
```

dereferencing a uninitialised pointer - undefined behaviour.

Change it to

```
int num;
num = atoi(argv[0]);
```

or

```
int *num = malloc(sizeof(int));
*num = atoi(argv[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Num is a pointer, that points to nothing. 
Correct it in

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("%s", argv[0]);
    pthread_t tid_main;
    pthread_t tid_fib;
    int ret;
    int num;
    num = atoi(argv[0]);
```

Take note that this means that the whole main function code has to treat num as a `int` and not `int *`

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a segfault because `num` isn't initialized to point to anything (or rather, the compiler is probably making it a null pointer). You then try to assign a variable to this garbage pointer.

You'll have to `malloc` some memory for it to use or just declare it as a static variable and create a pointer to it where necessary using unary `&`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int* num;
*num = atoi(argv[0]);
```

1. `num` is a pointer and it should be pointing to some valid memory location before writing something to it. In your case you don't do this so you see segmentation fault.
2. `argv[0]`  will always be the name of the program if argc is greater than 0.

> If the value of argc is greater than zero, the array members argv[0]
>   through  argv[argc-1] inclusive shall contain pointers to strings,
>   which are given implementation-defined values by the host environment
>   prior to program startup. The intent is to supply to the program
>   information determined prior to program startup from elsewhere in the
>   hosted environment. [...]
>
> If the value of argc is greater than zero,
>   the string pointed to by argv[0] represents the program name;
>   argv[0][0] shall be the null character if the program name is not
>   available from the host environment. [...]

PS: `atoi(NULL)` causes a crash and `argv[0]` might be NULL.